# Why CloseMainWindow() close my command screen instead of the activate window in C#?

Tags: c#, speech-recognition

I would like to use a C# Speech Recognition program to open and close files but when I say Close, my program close my console and not the program that I am using like vlc when I launch a .wmv file. Can you explain me why this is happening ?

Here is the code of my SpeechRecognition function :

```
private static Process lastStartedProcess;
    private static void _recognizer_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)//Méthode qui s'active lorsque l'ordi reconnait la phrase
    {



        if (e.Result.Text == "test")//e.Result contains the recognized text
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The test was successful");
        }

        else if (e.Result.Text == "exit")
        {
            _completed.Set(); //Calling the Set method will end the program
        }

        else if (e.Result.Text == " music")
        {
           lastStartedProcess = Process.Start(@"C:\Users\Public\Music\Sample Music\");
        }

        else if (e.Result.Text == " Pictures")
        {
           lastStartedProcess = Process.Start(@"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Desert.jpg");//En appelant music, j'affecte le process music a ma variable process

        }

        else if (e.Result.Text == " Movies")
        {
           lastStartedProcess = Process.Start(@"C:\Users\Public\Videos\Sample Videos\Wildlife.wmv");

        }

        else if (e.Result.Text == "Close")
        {
            if (lastStartedProcess != null)
            {

                lastStartedProcess.CloseMainWindow();//Ici je ferme le process qui est present dans ma variable process en appelant CloseMainWindow
                lastStartedProcess.WaitForExit();
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: So, you want to close the last opened program from your application?

Comment: Well, at this time yes, but I think i will enhanced that code like if i said close music, it will close the music program but not the browser for example. But first I want to work on that code step by step

Comment: You don't need to update the code in your question if it's just the code currently in one of the answers. You've now made your question not make any sense because the code shown *doesn't* close your application, which is what the question title and your narrative say happens.

Comment: Oh yeah you're right I wasn't paying attention for this precious details..Sorry.. So how can I fix this ? And if I need to update my code for explaining myelf i will have to put in in a new answer or do I have to explain myself with the 500 characters ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Process.GetCurrentProcess() will get your speech recognition process. You need to take a reference to the Process instance returned from the Process.Start calls.